# Catalan numbers and numbers of subsequence

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Given a set of numbers {$1,2,...,n$}, I want to find the number of permutations without 3-term subsequence of '1-3-2' pattern

Now this would be $A_n = n! - U_n$, where $A_n$ is the number of acceptable permutations and $U_n$ is the number of unacceptable permutations.

I have a vague idea that I should be using the Catalan numbers to consider cases of $U_n$. I could think of this as the parentheses problem where "(" is the low number, "A" is the high number, and ")" is the high number but I am unsure this works.

Would this be a valid argument? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical problem in the theorem of "permutation avoidance".
I'm not sure what you mean by "acceptable" permutations; ones which have
no $132$ patterns or ones which have a $132$ pattern. I'll let $C_n$
be the permutations with no $132$ patterns; clearly $C_n=n!$ for $n\le2$.

For a general permutation on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, thought of as a word,
to be $132$-avoiding it must have the form $w\,n\,w'$ for some $k$ where
$w'$ is a $132$-avoiding word on $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and
$w'$ is a $132$-avoiding word on $\{k+1,\ldots,n-1\}$. For a given $k$
the number of such words is $C_kC_{n-k-1}$ and so we get the recurrence
$$C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_kC_{n-k-1}$$
which may be familiar.

Comment: @Corp.andLtd. In the jargon of permutation patterns, $243$ **is** a $132$ pattern. There's an order-isomorphism between $\{2,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$ taking the first to the second.